# How to Remove Characters and Count Occurrences from Array to CSV File

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to remove certain single quotes and spaces, as well as capture the number of occurrences of a certain character, then move this into two columns of a csv file.

Using below:

```
a = []

for linenumber,line in enumerate(orig):
    if linenumber >2 and linenumber <7:
        a.append(np.array(list(orig[linenumber])))

print(np.array(a).T)
```

I get:

```
[[' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 ['3' '1' '7' '3']
 [' ' '1' '2' '1']
 [' ' ' ' '5' '5']]
```

Along with a separate array (b) using the same method in the same format with variable amounts of 'X's and spaces each line.

How would I create a csv where one column holds (a), and the second the number of 'X's in each line from a numpy array? I apologize, I'm very new to this, thank you in advance.

For example, I need something similar to below:

```
' ', '0'
'3173', '3'
'121', '6'
'55', '9'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in tools for string manipulation and counting substrings. Here are some examples on how you might use them:

```
my_string = "Walla Walla, Washington"
# You can count how many times a certain substring occurs in a string
Wa_count = my_string.count("Wa")
print(Wa_count) # 3 times
ll_count = my_string.count("ll")
print(ll_count) # 2 times
```

You can join lists of strings together with a separator of your choice. Every string has a `.join()` method that takes an *iterable* object which has elements that are all strings, and joins them together with the original string as a separator. An example probably demonstrates this best:

```
alist = ["John", "Mary", "Jane"]
with_ands = " and ".join(alist)
print(with_ands)
# "John and Mary and Jane"

atuple = ("John", "Mary", "Jane")
with_comma_space = ", ".join(atuple)
print(with_comma_space)
# "John, Mary, Jane"

some_date = ["04", "04", "2019"]
date_hyphen = "-".join(some_date)
print(date_hyphen)
# "04-04-2019"

import numpy as np
# This even works with empty strings
np_arr = np.array(['3', '1', '7', '3'])
np_array_example = ''.join(np_arr)
print(np_array_example)
# "3173"
```

Remember to always pass in an array/list/tuple/dict that only consists of strings. You can read more about strings here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Lastly, `.strip()` on strings removes whitespace on both sides. Also, since `.join()` returns a string, you can chain join and strip together. Tying it all together:

```
my_list = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['3', '1', '7', '3'], [' ', '1', '2', '1'], [' ', ' ', '5', '5']]

for inner_list in my_list:
    result = ''.join(inner_list).strip()
    print(result)
```

This will print, starting with a blank line because the first result is the empty string `""`:

```
3173
121
55
```

Python also has a built-in csv module. Taken directly from the manual: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

This will write

```
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

So, essentially all you need to do is pass `spammwriter.writerow()` a list of strings, where each string is a column.